# If $x_k+y_k$ converges and $x_k$ is bounded, show both $x_k$ and $y_k$ converge

Tags: calculus, limits

Question is if $x_k+y_k \to s$ (all real numbers), and $|x_k| \le M$ for some $M \ge 0 $, show $x_k \to x$ for some $x$ and $y_k \to y$ for some $y$ and $x+y=z$. I am new to this so I want an example how to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x_k=(-1)^k$ and $y_k=-(-1)^k$ to see that the statement is wrong.